# Visual Studio Team Services & Microsoft SCSM integration

Tags: azure-devops

My team is planning on using TFS as our ALM tool. We are evaluating both on-premise and hosted options. One of the requirements for TFS implementation is the ability to integrate with our on-premise ticketing system Microsoft SCSM. I've found a couple of ways to perform the integration with on-premise TFS. However, in terms of hosted option (VS Team Services), I haven't been able to find any information. Is an integration of on-premise SCSM with VS Team Services possible? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SCSM can integrate with Visual Studio Team Services through API with PowerShell (e.g. [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/overview)), which is similar to integrate with TFS.

Steps:

1. Install Visual Studio Team Explorer/Visual Studio
2. Install Service Manager Authoring Tool
3. Open Authoring Tool and select File=>New to create a new management pack (e.g. TFS.Integrations.xml)
4. Open Management Pack Explorer Window
5. Right Click Workflows=>Create
6. Enter the name of your workflow (e.g. CreateTFSTaskFromNewIncident)
7. On the Trigger Condition tab, select Run only when a database objects meets specified conditions.
8. Select the Incident class, using the Browse button.  Make sure the Change Event is When an object of the selected class is created.  Then click the Additional Criteria button.
9. For additional criteria, select the Classification Category and set it equal to Software Problems. This ensures that only New Software Problem Incidents will create a task in TFS.
10. Click Create and close
11. From Script Activities | General Script Activities, drag a Windows PowerShell Script Activity onto the workspace.  In the details window, change the name of the activity to be CreateTFSTaskFromNewIncident. Then, in the Details window, select Script Parameters, and click the ellipse button. This opens the Configure a Script Activity.  Click the Script Properties tab.  This is where I can get values from the incident that triggers the workflow and use those values in our PowerShell.
12. Add parameters that you want
13. Simple PowerShell script

Code:

```
#Load TFS PowerShell Snap-in
if ((Get-PSSnapIn -Name Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null)
{
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell
}

$Tfs2015AssembliesPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer"
Add-Type -Path "$Tfs2015AssembliesPath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$Tfs2015AssembliesPath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$Tfs2015AssembliesPath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$Tfs2015AssembliesPath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Common.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$Tfs2015AssembliesPath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$Tfs2015AssembliesPath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi.dll"
#Add-Type -Path "$Tfs2015AssembliesPath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$Tfs2015AssembliesPath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$Tfs2015AssembliesPath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll"

#TFS Server Collection
[string] $tfsCollectionUrl = "[collection url]"

#Get Team Project Collection
$teamProjectCollection = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory]::GetTeamProjectCollection($tfsCollectionUrl)

#Get Work Item Store object
$ws = $teamProjectCollection.GetService([type]"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore")

#Get Team Project
$proj = $ws.Projects["project name"]

#Get the Work Item Type to create
$wit = $proj.WorkItemTypes["Task"]

#Create a new work item of that type
$workitem = $wit.NewWorkItem()

#Set work item properties
$workItem.Title = "title"
$workItem.Description = "des"
$workitem.AreaPath = "XXX"
$workitem.IterationPath = "XXX"

#Save work item
$workItem.Save()
```

14. Click save, then it generates necessary DLL and XML files (check in windows explorer)
15. Copy DLL files to Service Manger Management Server (e.g. C:\Program Files\Microsoft System Center 2012 R2\Service Manager)
16. Open Service Manager Console
17. Go to Administrative workspace=>Management Packs=>Import
18. Select TFS.Integrations.xml=>Import
19. Go to Work Items=>Incident Management=>Create Incident, after create incident, it will create task work item with previous PowerShell Script
20. Go to Administration=>Workflows=>Status
21. Select corresponding workflow (CreateTFSTaskFromNewIncident) and check the result.

These articles can help you. ([1](http://www.systemcentercentral.com/day-28lets-integrate-system-center-service-manager-team-foundation-server/), [2](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/906d2520-ff49-4511-a710-858a00de4204/system-center-service-manager-integration-with-tfs-online?forum=systemcenterservicemanager))

Comment: Rather than putting links to off-site resources, put the actual content in the answer. Links tend to disappear over time. If someone looks at this answer in 5 years, the answer should still be correct. An answer that says "look here" and "here" represents a site that no longer exists isn't useful.